# Is it possible to get to the code from egg-link?

Tags: python, egg

I made some modifications to the code for a deep learning model implemented in MxNet.
On my local computer, I installed MxNet by conda/pip, so I could just go to the installation folder, where I found the files where the model architecture is specified and made my changes. The structure is like:

```
.../environment_folder/lib/python3.8/site-packages/
    - gluoncv/model_zoo/action_recognition/i3d_resnet.py
    - mxnet/gluon/block.py
```

and I made my changes to these files.
Now, I need to do the same on another machine, where MxNet has been compiled from source. I looked into the analogous installation folder, and I found the following structure:

```
.../environment_folder/lib/python3.8/site-packages/
    - gluoncv/model_zoo/action_recognition/i3d_resnet.py
    - mxnet.egg-link
```

i.e., I found the gluoncv folder, but instead of the mxnet one there is a egg-link. I honestly didn't know about egg files, I've been searching around and found it was an old way of packaging python files before wheels and pip. Is there any way I can open the link and get to the folder it is presumably pointing to?

Answer (score 0):

If you can open a python shell prompt (with the environment loaded) on the machine in question, try:

```
import mxnet
mxnet.__file__
```